# layer name is different in ArcGis Runtime 100

Tags: ios, swift, arcgis-runtime

I just updated my ArcGis sdk to use sdk version 100.2.1.

Previously to get the layer name I was using

```
AGSFeatureLayer *featureLayer = (AGSFeatureLayer *) layer;
layerName = featureLayer.serviceLayerName
```

and now In the sdk 100.2.1 there is no parameter name

`layerName = layer?.name`

But it returning the different string

in 10.2.1 it is returing POI
and in 100.2.1 it is returning Position Of Images

I have a backed loagic already implemented 
so is there any way to get the same service name in run time 100 ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want the service's name and not the layer's name:

```
layerName = (layer?.featureTable as? AGSServiceFeatureTable)?.tableName
```

If you are going to be working with offline workflows, or you're not sure and want to future-proof yourself in case that happens down the line, you can be a little broader in your scoping (see the class hierarchy diagram [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/latest/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_arc_g_i_s_feature_table.html)) and use:

```
layerName = (layer?.featureTable as? AGSArcGISFeatureTable)?.tableName
```

**Update:**
Note, as you mentioned in your response, you need to make sure the feature table is loaded, so something like this is likely more appropriate:

```
let serviceLayerTable = layer?.featureTable as? AGSServiceFeatureTable
serviceLayerTable?.load(completion: { error in
    guard error == nil else {
        print("Error loading table: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
    if let layerName = serviceLayerTable?.tableName {

    }
})
```

You can read from the `layerInfo` if you like, but the `tableName` property should work for you (once the table is loaded :)).

Comment: thnks but i also tried this. It is returning empty string. I just figure out a solution for this.

Comment: Ah, my oversight. Sorry. Yes, you should make sure the table is loaded before reading the name. I'll update my reply.

Answer (score 0):

While doing research I found that in the **arcgis sdk 10 for android** we are getting the service name from the **layerInfo parameter** of feature layer **but in ios there is not any layerInfo parameter** and we have a direct parameter serviceLayerName to get the service name of layer.

So i found that in **ArcGis sdk 100 arcgis introduce the layer info parameter in feature layer**.

```
let serviceFeatureTable = featureLayer?.featureTable
serviceFeatureTable.load { (error) in
     if let layerName = serviceFeatureTable.layerInfo?.serviceLayerName {

     }
}
```